# Merge sort not showing all the answers in C

Tags: c, file, sorting, while-loop, merge

I'm making a merge sort from these 2 files:

FILE 1

> federicoazurraga 11445696 31/12/1989
>   fernandocardozo 14588898 12/6/1970
>   lucianochavez 15478855 25/12/1992
>   juliagonzales 21458763 24/11/1974
>   francolomero 22417444 24/11/1989
>   agustincastellano 24365211 30/5/1985
>   martakim 26544153 4/3/1986
>   joaquinazorda 28741536 4/6/1988
>   nicolasweinber 34125652 14/7/1988
>   juanpardo 35459896 2/10/1994
>   paulafeiman 38746369 4/4/1983
>   martincurzel 38937133 21/11/1996
>   carlagarcia 40412478 3/4/1964
>   pedroquiroga 45668745 22/4/1994
>   horaciofernandez 54769956 21/6/1985
>   nada 999999999 99/99/9999

FILE 2

> camilaoraidea 9547698 23/4/1935
>   paulapomez 12445687 14/1/1956
>   ricardoreinas 14746966 4/5/1964
>   oscardias 14784411 25/12/1977
>   gabrielduarte 19963351 12/7/1969
>   hernancrespo 22045369 22/10/1988
>   soladmiral 22457869 31/5/1979
>   walterdominguez 32877999 17/2/1978
>   florenciahurni 33415222 22/11/1988
>   damianbogado 39478555 4/3/1999
>   kevinpolman 39789412 2/7/1997
>   oliverutirriaga 40412536 23/7/2000
>   mariagonzales 43568744 15/4/2002
>   ulisesiralon 48745737 14/6/2003
>   facundokumis 50478741 14/5/2004
>   nada 999999999 99/99/9999

```
typedef struct
{
int d;
int m;
int a;
}tfecha;


typedef struct
{
char nombre[20];
unsigned int dni;
tfecha nac;
}tperfil;

void mergesort(char archivo[], char archivo1[], FILE *file, const int h)
{
int dia, dia1, mes, mes1, ano, ano1;
unsigned int dni, dni1;
char nombre[20], nombre1[20];
tperfil buffer[1];
FILE *arch;
FILE *arch1;
printf("%s", archivo);
arch = fopen(archivo, "rt");
arch1 = fopen(archivo1, "rt");
fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
buffer[0].dni=dni;
buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
buffer[1].dni=dni1;
buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
printf("%i", buffer[0].nac.d);
if(h==1)//h is always 1 in this example
{
    while((dia < 99) && (dia1 < 99))
    {
        if(buffer[0].dni < buffer[1].dni)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[1].nombre, buffer[1].dni, buffer[1].nac.d, buffer[1].nac.m, buffer[1].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
            strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
            buffer[1].dni=dni1;
            buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
            buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
            buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The thing is that it prints the first name correctly, but then it just copies all FILE 1 without even checking FILE 2, like this:

> camilaoraidea 9547698 23/4/1935
>   federicoazurraga 11445696 31/12/1989
>   fernandocardozo 14588898 12/6/1970
>   lucianochavez 15478855 25/12/1992
>   juliagonzales 21458763 24/11/1974
>   francolomero 22417444 24/11/1989
>   agustincastellano 24365211 30/5/1985
>   martakim 26544153 4/3/1986
>   joaquinazorda 28741536 4/6/1988
>   nicolasweinber 34125652 14/7/1988
>   juanpardo 35459896 2/10/1994
>   paulafeiman 38746369 4/4/1983
>   martincurzel 38937133 21/11/1996
>   carlagarcia 40412478 3/4/1964
>   pedroquiroga 45668745 22/4/1994
>   horaciofernandez 54769956 21/6/1985

Comment: Step 1: When having issues involing input, insure the return value from `fscanf()` is as expected.  `if (fscan(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano) != 5) eixt(-1);`

Comment: `tperfil buffer[1];...strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);` does not make sense.  `buffer[1]` is outside `buffer[1];`.

Comment: I somehow fixed it just by adding one more space into the array: tperfil buffer[2];

Comment: it looks like there was problems with the scan not being able to use the last part of the array

Comment: @MartinCurzel The original `tperfil buffer[1];` creates an array with *one* entry. So of course `buffer[1]` (which is the second entry) can not be validly accessed. That's why changing to `tperfil buffer[2];` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue of memory allocation to `nombre`. Increase the size of `nombre` from 20 to maximum size that may be in both files + 1 for NULL character at end. Change it to 21 based on current data in question maximum size is 20 + 1 for NULL. Also change `tperfil buffer[1]` to `tperfil buffer[2]`.

I got output as:

```
camilaoraidea 9547698 23/4/1935
federicoazurraga 11445696 31/12/1989
paulapomez 12445687 14/1/1956
fernandocardozo 14588898 12/6/1970
ricardoreinas 14746966 4/5/1964
oscardias 14784411 25/12/1977
lucianochavez 15478855 25/12/1992
gabrielduarte 19963351 12/7/1969
juliagonzales 21458763 24/11/1974
hernancrespo 22045369 22/10/1988
francolomero 22417444 24/11/1989
soladmiral 22457869 31/5/1979
agustincastellano 24365211 30/5/1985
martakim 26544153 4/3/1986
joaquinazorda 28741536 4/6/1988
walterdominguez 32877999 17/2/1978
florenciahurni 33415222 22/11/1988
nicolasweinber 34125652 14/7/1988
juanpardo 35459896 2/10/1994
paulafeiman 38746369 4/4/1983
martincurzel 38937133 21/11/1996
damianbogado 39478555 4/3/1999
kevinpolman 39789412 2/7/1997
carlagarcia 40412478 3/4/1964
oliverutirriaga 40412536 23/7/2000
mariagonzales 43568744 15/4/2002
pedroquiroga 45668745 22/4/1994
ulisesiralon 48745737 14/6/2003
facundokumis 50478741 14/5/2004
```